# react bootstrap tabs component renders all tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, use-state

**I have a question that should be simple but I couldn't find a solution on SO so far or within the docs**

---

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/

For some reason my component renders all of my actual tabs instead of the active tab even though I have it set to only show the active tab... hoping someone can provide some insight, I have included the bootstrap and jquery CDN in my index.html to try to fix it but it doesn't make a difference

```
const [key, setKey] = useState("chart");
function CoinData(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs
        className="tabs"
        id="controlled-tab-example"
        activeKey={key}
        onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
        className="mb-3"
      >
        <Tab eventKey="chart" title="Charts">
          {allLoading ? (
            "Loading token data..."
          ) : (
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Symbol</th>
                  <th>In Eth</th>
                  <th>Liquidity</th>
                </tr>

                {allTokenData.tokens.map((token, index) => (
                  <tr className="row" key={index}>
                    <td>{token.id}</td>
                    <td>{token.symbol}</td>
                    <td>{parseFloat(token.derivedETH).toFixed(4)}</td>
                    <td>{token.totalLiquidity}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          )}
        </Tab>

        <Tab eventKey="track" title="Tracker">
          <Tracker />
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why is your state outside the component? Can you update question to include a full and complete component code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are very likely to forget importing bootstrap.css**

Here is a minimize working version of your code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function CoinData(props) {
  const [key, setKey] = useState("chart");
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs
        className="tabs"
        id="controlled-tab-example"
        activeKey={key}
        onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
      >
        <Tab eventKey="chart" title="Charts">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="track" title="Tracker">
        <h1>2</h1>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CoinData />, rootElement);
```

---

[image: Edit react-bootstrap tabs sample (forked)]

Comment: yep looks like that was it :P thanks a bunch, thought I just needed to import the component itself and just import the css in my index.html... didn't know there was that total import option for the css in node will keep a lookout for this in the future

Comment: Great! CSS will need to import in order to do all the styling magic :D